# Want to know reason behind NumberFormat Exception in my code

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parsefloat, value-of

I am trying to read file with BufferedReader and at the time of spliting each line of file I want to convert string data at 8th position to be converted to float.(count starts from 0 data)

below is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFloat {
    static BufferedReader bin;
    String line;
    void sumAmount() throws IOException //Perform calculation
    {

        bin =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Extras\\file.txt"));
        //String firstline = bin.readLine();
        while ((line = bin.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String data[] = line.split(",");
            //System.out.println(data[8]);
            System.out.println(Float.valueOf(data[8]));
            //System.out.println(java.lang.Float.parseFloat(data[8]))
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    TestFloat ts = new TestFloat();
    try {
        ts.sumAmount();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

for this code I am getting exception as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
    at TestFloat.sumAmount(TestFloat.java:17)
    at TestFloat.main(TestFloat.java:24)
```

one sample line of file.txt is :

```
20,20160518,262,20160518,00,F&O ABC DEBIT F 160518,000405107289,000405006220,5000000.00,5000000.00,0.00,,
```

I have tried with parseFloat and valueOf both function but it shows exception. What is the reason behind the fail?

Comment: Debug before coming here. Print out what that String token holds just before you try to parse it.

Comment: Before parsing value to a number format, you should check it for null and also check it's length should be greater than 0. It is possible to have blank value at 8th in some line in your txt file, which has caused the exception.

Comment: i have already tried printing data before parsing it. It gives same string as I want. its string 5000000.00..which it should be.

Comment: Not every time Student. You're using a while loop, and at least one time in that loop, it doesn't. You need to debug further.

Comment: can you please explain it more?I am not getting you.

Comment: Again, uncomment the println's and see what they say. Change them so that they always print something: `System.out.println("data[8]: " + data[8]);` and you'll see the last time the while loop loops, you're getting an empty String. Then do further debugging to see why.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got to know Importance of debugging now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

as the error states you're attempting to parse an empty `string`.

one solution is to use an `if` statement to guard off the `NumberFormatException`(*only* for empty `strings` that is, you could still get the `NumberFormatException` for unparseable `strings`).

```
if(data[8] != null && data[8].length() > 0){
     System.out.println(Float.valueOf(data[8]));
     System.out.println(java.lang.Float.parseFloat(data[8]));
}
```

you'll need to go through the debugger step by step and see what is the real issue behind it.